# java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed at DriverManager.getConnection(url) on Bamboo only

Tags: java, sqlite, bamboo

I am in the uncomfortable situation where some tests work locally, but cause an exception once pushed to the repository and the build by Bamboo.

The error that occurs on Bamboo is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed
```

It occurs here, in the line `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)`:

```
    public RequirementRepository(String folder) throws SQLException, DatabaseNotConnectedException {

        new File(folder).mkdirs();
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + folder + "/requirement.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
            [Very long SQL statement]
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, this does not fail always, but only sometimes.

I've already checked the URL in both succeeding and failing cases, and it is the same in both cases:
`jdbc:sqlite:Test_Database/requirement.db`

Any ideas what could cause or affect this, and why it only happens on Bamboo and not on my local machine? Even if I delete the database from my local machine so it has to be newly created, I can't replicate the error locally.

---

EDIT:

Here's the stack trace up to the point where it enters local code:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed
java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:478)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.errmsg_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.errmsg(NativeDB.java:144)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(NativeDB.java:78)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:195)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:243)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:116)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:90)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at dom_requirement.model.RequirementRepository.<init>(RequirementRepository.java:225)
```

Line 225 is:

```
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

---

EDIT 2:

This notably also appears when the connection is being set like this:

```
    public WorkspaceManager(String folder) throws SQLException {

        new File(folder).mkdirs();
        databaseConnectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:" + folder + "/workspace.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseConnectionUrl)){
            try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
                [Very long SQL statement]
            }
        }
    }
```

In that case, the line causing the error is:

```
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseConnectionUrl)){
```

The stacktrace itself remains unchanged.

---

EDIT 3:

I now found a way to make it work, although that particular solution seems more like a workaround around a glitch than a proper solution, so I am still interested in hearing about ideas what might be the actual cause and how to fix it.

As mentioned above, the error appears only on tests on Bamboo. It's a total of 134 tests spread across 14 classes, all of which inherit from a RequirementControllerTest abstract class.

In the version where it fails on Bamboo, the SQL Connection is created in a @BeforeEach method in the RequirementControllerTest, so a fresh connection is created for each of the 134 tests.

We managed to get it to pass by switching this @BeforeEach method to a @BeforeAll method, so now the SQL Connection is only created 14 times instead of 134, and interestingly this works on Bamboo.

So the thing I wonder now is, how can this work if it's only done 14 times, but not if it's done 134 times? And why does it only happen on Bamboo?

Comment: According to [How to fix 'java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668107/how-to-fix-java-sql-sqlexception-the-database-has-been-closed-problem) this error indicates that the database does not exist. You might want to try to specify an absolute path for the database file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path is wrongly formed in the `url` is invalid.

That is, this `jdbc:sqlite:Test_Database/requirement.db` is invalid path formed.

Update the code to this :

```
public RequirementRepository(String folder) throws SQLException, DatabaseNotConnectedException {
        File file = new File(folder);
        file.mkdirs();
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "/requirement.db";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement statement = conn.createStatement();) {
            [Very long SQL statement]
        } catch(SQLException e) {
           // TODO: throw exception.
        } 
    }
```

Note : `folder` field should contain the full path where the directory should be created.

For example :

```
String folder = "D:/Test_Database";
```

Follow this syntax :

`jdbc:sqlite:db_file_path` - here `db_file_path` should be an absolute or relative path.

For example :

```
jdbc:sqlite:D:/Test_Database/requirement.db or jdbc:sqlite:requirement.db
```

Follow this [blog](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)

Read this [Bamboo's working directory Atlassian Support](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/specifying-bamboo-s-working-directory-289277246.html).

Comment: @KiraResari Is this ok ?

Comment: Nope, I tried this, and the same error still persists. Note that it does work on my local machine with both variants though, but Bamboo still throws the same old error.

Comment: @KiraResari This should work. Check the path. Where is the Test_Database directory created in your local machine. Can you share that ?

Comment: Why yes, I wholeheartedly agree. This _should_ work. And locally, it does, but just not on Bamboo. I've already tried debugging it in various common ways, and none have lead me to success. That is why I posted a bounty on this. I wouldn't have done that if this was easy. Anyway, locally, the following connection string (surprisingly) works: `jdbc:sqlite:C:\projects\camelot\knight\db/workspace.db`. I'll also be posting the string from bamboo in case of a failure here as soon as I manage to get the bamboo builds working again, which broke over the weekend.

Comment: @KiraResari Ok !! I'm looking on this into more details. This link might be helpful - > https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/specifying-bamboo-s-working-directory-289277246.html

Comment: I would love to, but out Bamboo Builds are broken for some reason and right now, so I can't verify it now. I've been working the last 3 hours to get them to work again, but we're still stuck. However, please allow me to point out again that I think this is a very unlikely solution, as the tests pass if I create the connection using BeforeAll instead of BeforeEach, and even with BeforeEach some of the tests pass and others fail, even though the connection string is identical for both passing and failing tests. I already tried this before.

Comment: Just got Bamboo to work again, and the failing conenction urlis this:  `jdbc:sqlite:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/CAM-KNIG48-JOB1/knight/db/workspace.db`

Comment: @KiraResari Is `workspace.db` exists in that directory ? Or May be database doesn't exist. Or path may be wrong please check.

Comment: @KiraResari I have added a link in my answer. May be that can solve your problem regarding path.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think this is quite what I was looking for, so I won't be marking it as an answer, but since this gave me at least something to think about, I want you to have the bounty anyways.

Comment: @KiraResari   What problem are you facing right now ?  Is `workspace.db`exists in that directory ?

Comment: @KiraResari Is this a right directory `jdbc:sqlite:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/CAM-KNIG48-JOB1/knight/db` you are sending ?